# Number of combinations subject to constraints

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Consider the set of all possible vectors consist of $n$ positive integers, $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$, such that $1 \le x_i \le K$ ($K$ is a positive integer) for all $i$. There are of course $K^n$ such vectors.

I am trying to figure out how many vectors in this set have at least one pair $x_l$ and $x_m$, $l \ne m$, such that $x_l+x_m > P$ ($P$ is an integer, $P \ge 2$).

Basically, I can solve it by considering $x_i$ as i.i.d. random variables, distributed uniformly over the interval $[1,K]$, and then using the inclusion-exclusion principle. However, this solution involves discrete convolutions and the need to take into account the possible dependencies of pairs within $x_i$. As $n$ becomes larger, this solution method appears to become more and more difficult.

Does anyone see how to obtain a closed form solution, as a function of $n,K$ and $P$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume $K \ge P$.

First, consider how many vectors have a maximum value less than or equal to $P/2$: this is $\lfloor P/2 \rfloor^n$. None of these vectors satisfy the requirement.

Second, if $P/2 \lt M \lt P$ consider how many vectors have a single maximum of $M$ and all others less than or equal to $P-M$: this is $n (P-M)^{n-1}$ other vectors which do not satisfy the requirement.

So overall we get $\displaystyle K^n-\lfloor P/2 \rfloor^n-\sum_{P/2 \lt M \lt P} n (P-M)^{n-1} $ vectors which satisfy the requirement. Letting $j=P-M$, this can be rewritten as $\displaystyle K^n-\lfloor P/2 \rfloor^n- n \sum_{j=1}^{\lceil P/2\rceil-1} j^{n-1} .$